# Intern test framework hangs/does nothing when used with Appium 1.4.13 on an iOS device for mobile web

Tags: ios, selenium, appium, functional-testing, intern

I just started looking into using the intern test framework to write functional tests for our mobile web apps. I'm looking to run these tests on actual iOS devices.

I setup Appium as the selenium server talking to the intern client. It works as expected on the simulator (although I get 'method not implemented' for many of the touch related methods).

I then decided to configure everything to work on my iPhone 6 plus, running iOS 9.0.2

After much wrangling with instructions from [here](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?javascript#mobile-safari-on-a-real-ios-device), I got all the various pieces working in tandem (ios-webkit-debug-proxy, appium-server from the repo, etc.)

Finally, I decided to run my tests. When I run the test runner, Safari on my device starts up (via SafariLauncher App), and ios-webkit-debug-proxy and appium-server seem to be talking to each other. However, intern simply posts a 'created session on...' message, and then does nothing.

To ensure that the server was running properly, I decided to use a rest client to send it POST and GET requests using the [JSONWire Protocol](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) methods, and it seems to be loading the web-page url and responding to JSONWire requests. So clearly, something is going wrong with Appium talking to intern, or vice-versa.

Any help/insight on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I'm also in the unique position of having to run these locally, so using SauceLabs, BrowserStack, etc. is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working!!!

So the trick was to specify the `proxyUrl` config option.

My original conjecture was that there might have been some issues with `basePath`, etc., but I noticed my `console.log` statements that were outside of test cases were running properly.

That's when I noticed that the Safari page tried to navigate to `localhost` right after the test had started. This is my first time ever working with Intern or Appium or any Selenium stuff for that matter. Because you cannot access `localhost` (which in this case was meant for accessing the Intern server on my computer, since you're running the tests on your computer, and not on an external device), from the iPhone, I specified `proxyUrl` and `proxyPort` in the config, and specified my computer's local IP (192.168.x.x) and the Intern server port (9000). It still didn't work. I looked at the URL in Safari and noticed that it wasn't using the `proxyPort` field - so that the URL looked like: `192.168.x.x/__intern/clie..`. So I just tried to enter the port in the `proxyUrl` option - as that option's a string - `192.168.x.x:9000`. And voila - it worked!!!

So hopefully this helps some other soul looking to have a native mobile test working with this setup!